# how to ignore file to github and include the same file to heroku?

Tags: git, grails, heroku, github

I am trying to use grails mail plugin but i have the next problem, i have an app in heroku that use git to deploy, the app is also in github, when i read [mail plugin setting](http://grails.org/plugin/mail) i found it can use gmail setting and it fit in my scenario.

The problem is that in order to use the plugin i need to use my gmail credentials, i could externalize the config and use gitignore file and this fix to show credentials in github but in the other hand i need to deploy the app to heroku and will need the credentials

I hope i was able to explain my self, if not, feel free to edit it in order to find an answer. And thanks for your time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, this type of thing [should be set on Heroku using environment variables](http://12factor.net/config).

You could, for instance, [set an environment variables](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars#setting-up-config-vars-for-a-deployed-application) `GMAIL_USERNAME` and `GMAIL_PASSWORD` on Heroku like this:

```
heroku config:set GMAIL_USERNAME=me@gmail.com
heroku config:set GMAIL_PASSWORD=someth1ngS3cret
```

and then read those environment variables into your application. I'm not a Grails user, but in  a Python Django application I might use code like this in my `settings.py` file:

```python
GMAIL_USERNAME = os.getenv('GMAIL_USERNAME', 'default-username')
GMAIL_PASSWORD = os.getenv('GMAIL_PASSWORD', 'default-password')
```

You can now set your Gmail credentials to whatever you want in development (and other developers can too) by setting those two environment variables. When you deploy to Heroku, the variables are available to your code, so you can put the production values in there.

These variables can also be set through Heroku's web interface.

**Edit:**

It [looks like](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-grails#set-up-the-database) environment variables can be accessed in grails via `System.env.VARIABLE_NAME`:

> Configure your app to use this database by changing the `production` database configuration in `grails-app/conf/DataSource.groovy` to this:
>
> ```
> production {
>     dataSource {
>         dbCreate = "update"
>         driverClassName = "org.postgresql.Driver"
>         dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
>
>         uri = new URI(System.env.DATABASE_URL?:"postgres://test:test@localhost/test")
>
>         url = "jdbc:postgresql://"+uri.host+uri.path
>         username = uri.userInfo.split(":")[0]
>         password = uri.userInfo.split(":")[1]
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: Nice solution after your answer i found [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars) information in heroku documentation. Does anyone know how to access heroku config var from grails?

Comment: @user615274, I found something in the Heroku docs that may help. Please see the updated answer.

Comment: I tried to access heroku config vars using System.env.GMAIL_USERNAME or any other vars and i get null as a result, in the other hand i am available to access System.env.DATABASE_URL but in production, the problem here is how to access config var from local development environment

Comment: @user615274, [possibly `System.getenv('GMAIL_USERNAME')`](http://groovy.329449.n5.nabble.com/trying-to-get-environment-variable-inside-groovy-td358877.html)?

Comment: I found what looks like the possible solution it is described [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars#local-setup) in heroku documentation. I am about to tried

Comment: Now is working, @Chris solution work very well in local and production, the general instructions are explained in heroku config vars [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars). In order to get env vars from local you needs to create .env file inside root app and set inside the file the needed vars, start your framework from [foreman](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars#local-setup) that is already installed with Heroku Toolbelt in this case **foreman grails run-app**, and now our app has access to confirg vars setted inside .env file. Thanks for your time.

Comment: instead of foreman grails run-app it has to be foreman run grails run-app